# Lodash convert array of object to different structure

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

How can I transform from the `old` nested object array to the `new` flater one.

PLEASE NOTE: `userId`, `quizId`, and `answerId` are different values. They are strings and vary for each object in the array. So there are no issues of duplicates in the below before / after models

Model structure

```
const old = [{
  userId: string,
  quiz: [{
    quizId: string,
    createdAt: string,
    completedAt: string,
    answers: [{
      answerId: string,
      value: any,
      updatedAt: string
    }]
  }]
}]
```

```
const new = [{
  userId: string,
  quizId: string,
  createdAt: string,
  completedAt: string,
  responses: {
    answerId: {
      value: any,
      updatedAt: string
    }
  }
}]
```

Each object in the array is unique on the composite key of `userId` `quizId`. In the old object the record has an array of `answers` whilst in the new object it has an object of `responses` the data contained within each is identical (`answerId`, `value,` updatedAt`) but the structure is of course different.

Current solution.

```
const allUniqueUserIds = [...new Set(refactoredQuizs.map(quiz => quiz.userId))]

const usersQuizDto: UsersQuizsDto[] = allUniqueUserIds.map((id) => {
  const userQuizs = refactoredQuizs.filter(quiz => quiz.userId===id);
  return {
    RespondentID: id,
    Quizs: userQuizs.map(quiz => {
      return {
        StartedAt: (quiz.createdAt as any)?.toDate()?.toUTCString(),
        CompletedAt: (quiz.completedAt as any)?.toDate()?.toUTCString(),
        UpdatedAt: '',
        QuizId: quiz.quizId,
        Answers: _.toPairs(quiz.responses).map(([answerId, { value, updatedAt }]) => {
          return {
            AnswerId: answerId,
            Value: value,
            UpdatedAt: (updatedAt as any)?.toDate()?.toUTCString()
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: `quiz` and `answers` are arrays. Your approach will only work when there's only one quiz and only one answer.

Comment: Why do you think this? I have a solution that doesn't use lodash enough so it's quite verbose.

Comment: You cannot have duplicated properties, hence there will always be only one `responses.answerId`, and only one `quizId`, `createdAt`, `completedAt`, ...

Comment: I see, I've added a little more detail. As responses object will never contain a property `answerId`. This is a placeholder for a GUID. `answerID`, `userId`, and `quizId` are all GUID values.